# Silverstripe 3 - extend sitetree and layout

Tags: silverstripe

I'm a newbie in SilverStripe. I need to create a new page by extending a new class sitetree. My question is how to retrieve in the template something like $Layou which is used in the classic page.php. For example, in my template folder I would like to have a folder like "Layout" organized for new pages created from this.

this is the controller:

```
class WhitePage extends SiteTree {
    private static $db = array(
    );
    private static $has_one = array(
    );
}

class WhitePage_Controller extends ContentController {
    private static $allowed_actions = array(
    );

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
    }

    function index() {
        return $this->renderWith("WhitePage");
    }
}
```

i would like in the template directory create a folder name "whitepage" within the ".ss" file, and in the template use something like $whitepage instate of $Layout ...

How to do this?

thk, a lot
Francesco

Comment: As far as I know, you wouldn't easily be able to override `$Layout`. Beyond trying to organise your template folder differently, why exactly do you want to do it this way? Every site I have worked on, custom page templates are stored in the `mysite/templates/Layout` folder like usual and any modules that add new page templates are stored in `{my-module-name}/templates/Layout`.

Comment: my purpose is to create a new page that will no render the base page page.ss, in this case i need a withe page without the element inside page.ss (in themes/mytheme/templates/Page.ss)

Comment: You can just put your WhitePage.ss in themes/mytheme/templates and it will be used instead of Page.ss
More info about Silverstripe template engine here: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/templates

Comment: this is what I did, but i'm interested in something more complex, and reusable. Because if I need to reuse whitepage for a new extended page i will do ...

Comment: You could use renderWith since it can handle arrays and the first valid one will be used. See here: http://api.silverstripe.org/master/class-ViewableData.html#_renderWith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the master *WhitePage.ss* template with several page types by extending your `WhitePage` class. Then you can use the `$Layout` as normal to call your custom layout template.

**WhitePage**

```php
class WhitePage extends SiteTree {
}

class WhitePage_Controller extends ContentController {
    private static $allowed_actions = array(
    );

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

**CustomWhitePage**

```php
class CustomWhitePage extends WhitePage {
}

class CustomWhitePage_Controller extends WhitePage_Controller {
    private static $allowed_actions = array(
    );

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

In your *themes/mytheme* folder or *mysite* folder create your templates like so:

```
templates/Page.ss
templates/WhitePage.ss
templates/Layout/Page.ss
templates/Layout/WhitePage.ss
templates/Layout/CustomWhitePage.ss
```

Your `Layout/WhitePage.ss` and `Layout/CustomWhitePage.ss` will use the `templates/WhitePage.ss` parent template while any page that extends `Page` will use `templates/Page.ss`.

Make sure you call `?flush=all` for your templates to be loaded the first time through.